# Combining Results From Same Query Into One new Result - MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table that have several records linked to one particular tag.  For example, this query

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE tag = 'tag1'
```

will return this

```
equipment_id   |   tag   |   acquisition_cost   |   purchase_date   | user
1                  tag1         200.05                 null            null
5                  tag1          null                02-02-2012        null
19                 tag1          null                  null            jsmith
```

I would like to combine all the results that have the same tag, and insert into a new table so that I get this:

```
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE tag = 'tag1'

equipment_id   |   tag   |   acquisition_cost   |   purchase_date   |    user
[]                  tag1         200.05                 02-02-2012       jsmith
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you want to do if there is more than one value for the same tag in one of those fields?

Comment: What data type is value `[]` of??

Comment: Oops, I meant to put in an int value.  This will be auto-incrementing on table 2.

Comment: Why is this getting rated down?  Why penalize someone for trying to improve their mysql skills?

Comment: Technically, helping you to do this query would be making your mySQL skills worse. Usually when someone is writing a query like this it is a bad idea from the outset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is only one value per column per tag then you can use a query like this:

```
SELECT 
  tag,
  MAX(acquisition_cost),
  MAX(purchase_date),
  MAX(user) 
FROM `table1`
GROUP BY tag
```

If there is more than one value then I'd highly not recommend collapsing the data like this - you should rethink your design.

Comment: Thanks, liquorvicar.  This data is actually the result of several different excel reports, and I've been tasked with trying to consolidate the disparate records.

Comment: Don't consolidate them into a single row. Use a normalized table structure instead. The resulting table you are trying to create will be a major pain to use.

Comment: @JohnFx I'm not sure we have enough info to say that. If there is one and only one value in each column per tag then it may be that each tag represents a piece of equipment and hence one table may be the way to go.

Comment: @liquorvicar In the comments on the OP he indicates he wants to concatenate values.

Comment: @JohnFx He indicates that he hasn't really thought about it and he hasn't indicated whether or not there is more than one value per column per tag. Which is why I gave the solution if there is only one value per column. But I agree that he should rethink his design if there is more than one value per column per tag (i.e. avoid concatenation like the plague!)